# .d.ts for a module with methods that return itself

Tags: javascript, typescript, .d.ts

I have node.js module that can be used like this (the actual functionality is just for example's sake):

```
const Grower = require('grower');
const grown = Grower.grow(100); // Returns 110, because default growth rate is 1.1
```

or:

```
const ConfiguredGrower = require('grower').withGrowthRate(1.2);
const grown = ConfiguredGrower.grow(100); // Returns 120
```

or:

```
const ConfiguredTwiceGrower = require('grower')
    .withGrowthRate(1.2)
    .withGrowthRate(1.4);
```

(OK, it makes no sense to set growthRate twice... but imagine there are other chainable
configuration methods).

Internally this is implemented using ES6 classes:

```
class Grower {
   constructor(growthRate) { this.rate = growthRate; }

   withGrowthRate() { return new Grower(growthRate); }

   grow(n) { return n * this.rate; }
}

module.exports = new Grower(1.1);
```

... and this works.

I have added a `.d.ts` type declaration for this, but because the functions are on both in the default export, and members of the interface returned by `withGrowthRate`, I have duplicated the declaration:

```
export interface Grower {
    withGrowthRate: number => Grower,
    grow: number => number,
}

export function withGrowthRate(number): Grower,
export function grow(number): number,
```

What clean way is there to remove this duplication?

I *think* I'd prefer not to expose this stuff as TS classes (I don't want clients to use `new`).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use `export =` syntax for this:

```js
class Grower {
  withGrowthRate(growthRate: number): Grower;
  grow(time: number): number;
}
const defaultGrower: Grower;
export = defaultGrower;
```

Comment: Thank you. This doesn't seem to get picked up by VS Code when importing the module from JS.